# Select data from two tables and save as cvs

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've got 2 tables:

Table 1
[image]

and Table 2
[image]

Now I'm tryning to get from Table 2 field "Name" that is equal to eo_venue_id from Table 1. For example in Table 1 eo_venue_id has value 29 so i need to get the field "Name" from Table 2 where term_id is 29. Than I need to export all this data to csv where the columns should be:

Name | _city | _address

How can I do this?

Ok, I've got this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
name
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_eo_venuemeta WHERE wp_eo_venuemeta.meta_key = '_address' AND wp_eo_venuemeta.eo_venue_id = wp_terms.term_id) as "Adres"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_eo_venuemeta WHERE wp_eo_venuemeta.meta_key = '_city' AND wp_eo_venuemeta.eo_venue_id = wp_terms.term_id) as "City"
FROM wp_terms
ORDER BY
name
```

Is it ok? Now, how to export this to CSV?

Comment: I've add an update :)

Comment: Check this link for selecting into a file with specified delimiters : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html

Comment: Are you getting the required output by the query specified by you?